# Class templates and explicit specialization of functions

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors

Suppose we have the following class template:

```
  template<typename T, size_t m, size_t n>
  class Matrix {
    /* Implementation/Declaration is probably irrelevant and has been omitted. */
  };
```

I want to specialize a certain function for my template class.

```
template<> template<typename T, size_t m, size_t n>
inline std::wstring Microsoft::VisualStudio:CppUnitTestFramework::ToString(const Matrix<T, m, n> &mtrx) {
  /* Definition omitted */
}
```

(And yes, the function I'm specializing is a real function that shouldn't be too hard to find.)

I see no reason as to why the above code is wrong, yet I get the following (extremely unhelpful) error message when compiling (before you ask, proper files have been included):

```
C2244: 'ToString': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

Since people will inevitably ask for it, I might as well include the prototypes for the function I'm specializing:

```
template <typename Q> static std::wstring ToString (const Q& q);
```

And, I have no issue with specializing it with classes without template arguments (eg: std::string).

Comment: Get rid of the `template <>` part.

Comment: I've tried that already. It did not work. (Exact same error message.)

Comment: Did you declare it first within the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a specialization - there ain't no such thing as a partial specialization of function templates. Instead, you want an overload. And an overload cannot be defined outside of the namespace - you need to reopen the namespace. Something like this:

```
namespace Microsoft {
namespace VisualStudio {
namespace CppUnitTestFramework {

template<typename T, size_t m, size_t n>
std::wstring ToString(const Matrix<T, m, n> &mtrx) {
  /* Definition omitted */
}

}}}  // end namespaces
```